# C# not all code paths return a value try catch

Tags: c#

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get around the error with the below code.  In this case below I want to return the datatable inside the catch as null.

```
    public static DataTable DTTable(string mysqlQuery, out DataTable DTTableTable)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlQuery, Connection);
            DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
            DataTable DataDTTablesDT = new DataTable();
            DataDTTables.Fill(DataDTTablesDT);
            DTTableTable = DataDTTablesDT;
            EventLog.WriteEntry(StaticStringClass.crawlerID, "Returning Sucessful datatable query:  "+mysqlQuery);
            return DTTableTable;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            string messageString = "Could not fill database for query:  " + mysqlQuery + " because of error:  " + ex.Message.ToString();
            LoggingClass.GenericLogging(messageString);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Not a big deal, but I recommend changing your local variables to always start with lower-case letters, even if you intend to return them from the function.  It makes it easier to tell that they are local variables.  You've already doing that with `messageString`, for example.

Comment: Returning `out` parameter is quite silly, no offence meant. Why such design? Either have it as return value, or as `out` parameter.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your catch block, add a return:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // your code
    return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't return anything after your `catch` block finishes execution.

You need to return some `DataTable` for that case.

```
public static DataTable DTTable(string mysqlQuery, out DataTable DTTableTable)
{
    DataTable result;
    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlQuery, Connection);
        DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
        DataTable DataDTTablesDT = new DataTable();
        DataDTTables.Fill(DataDTTablesDT);
        DTTableTable = DataDTTablesDT;
        EventLog.WriteEntry(StaticStringClass.crawlerID, "Returning Sucessful datatable query:  "+mysqlQuery);
        result = DTTableTable;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string messageString = "Could not fill database for query:  " + mysqlQuery + " because of error:  " + ex.Message.ToString();
        LoggingClass.GenericLogging(messageString);
        result = null;
    }
    return result; //<--- executes even if an exception is thrown
}
```

Comment: It doesn't strictly have to be *after* the catch block completes.  The OP could return inside the catch block, too (probably at the end of it).  Of course your code also correctly solves the problem (and I prefer the one-return style, as you have written here).

Answer (score 2):

try

```
public static DataTable DTTable(string mysqlQuery, out DataTable DTTableTable)
    {
    DataTable Result = null;
    try
    {
    MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlQuery, Connection);
    DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
    DataTable DataDTTablesDT = new DataTable();
    DataDTTables.Fill(DataDTTablesDT);
    DTTableTable = DataDTTablesDT;
    EventLog.WriteEntry(StaticStringClass.crawlerID, "Returning Sucessful datatable query:  "+mysqlQuery);
    Result =  DataDTTablesDT;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    string messageString = "Could not fill database for query:  " + mysqlQuery + " because of error:  " + ex.Message.ToString();
    LoggingClass.GenericLogging(messageString);
    }

return Result;
}
```

EDIT:

**Version 1 (no out param because it is redundant):**

```
public static DataTable DTTable(string mysqlQuery)
    {
    DataTable Result = null;
    try
    {
    MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlQuery, Connection);
    DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
    DataTable DataDTTablesDT = new DataTable();
    DataDTTables.Fill(DataDTTablesDT);
    EventLog.WriteEntry(StaticStringClass.crawlerID, "Returning Sucessful datatable query:  "+mysqlQuery);
    Result =  DataDTTablesDT;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    string messageString = "Could not fill database for query:  " + mysqlQuery + " because of error:  " + ex.Message.ToString();
    LoggingClass.GenericLogging(messageString);
    }
```

return Result;
}

**Version 2 - not return Value (just out param):**

```
public static void DTTable(string mysqlQuery, out DataTable DTTableTable)
    {
    DTTableTable = null;
    try
    {
    MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlQuery, Connection);
    DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
    DataTable DataDTTablesDT = new DataTable();
    DataDTTables.Fill(DataDTTablesDT);
    EventLog.WriteEntry(StaticStringClass.crawlerID, "Returning Sucessful datatable query:  "+mysqlQuery);
    DTTableTable = DataDTTablesDT;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    string messageString = "Could not fill database for query:  " + mysqlQuery + " because of error:  " + ex.Message.ToString();
    LoggingClass.GenericLogging(messageString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return null inside the catch, then just return null inside the catch:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string messageString = "Could not fill database for query:  " + mysqlQuery + " because of error:  " + ex.Message.ToString();
        LoggingClass.GenericLogging(messageString);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static DataTable DTTable(string mysqlQuery, out DataTable DTTableTable)
{
    try
    {
       ....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ....
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the alternative code path is the `catch` block and you're not re-throwing the exception you still need to return either `null` or a `DataTable`.

You can do this in the `catch` block or right after it.

I'd also say that your `out DataTable DTTableTable` parameter in your `DTTable` method is redundant and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

put simple return  statement with null value .I hope this will solve your issue.